How to add js/css style to svelte-kit project
I have a js effect called color changin in codepen and i dont how implement it into my svelte-kit project like I tried to implementing this directly into app.css and app.html but it didn't work I dont how to implement it into svelte-kit project and there is my project structure. and here is the codes of effect
<canvas id="c"> </canvas>

canvas {
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

var c = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var cH;
var cW;
var bgColor = "#FF6138";
var animations = [];
var circles = [];

var colorPicker = (function() {
  var colors = ["#FF6138", "#FFBE53", "#2980B9", "#282741"];
  var index = 0;
  function next() {
    index = index++ < colors.length-1 ? index : 0;
    return colors[index];
  }
  function current() {
    return colors[index]
  }
  return {
    next: next,
    current: current
  }
})();

function removeAnimation(animation) {
  var index = animations.indexOf(animation);
  if (index > -1) animations.splice(index, 1);
}

function calcPageFillRadius(x, y) {
  var l = Math.max(x - 0, cW - x);
  var h = Math.max(y - 0, cH - y);
  return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(l, 2) + Math.pow(h, 2));
}

function addClickListeners() {
  document.addEventListener("touchstart", handleEvent);
  document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleEvent);
};

function handleEvent(e) {
    if (e.touches) { 
      e.preventDefault();
      e = e.touches[0];
    }
    var currentColor = colorPicker.current();
    var nextColor = colorPicker.next();
    var targetR = calcPageFillRadius(e.pageX, e.pageY);
    var rippleSize = Math.min(200, (cW * .4));
    var minCoverDuration = 750;
    
    var pageFill = new Circle({
      x: e.pageX,
      y: e.pageY,
      r: 0,
      fill: nextColor
    });
    var fillAnimation = anime({
      targets: pageFill,
      r: targetR,
      duration:  Math.max(targetR / 2 , minCoverDuration ),
      easing: "easeOutQuart",
      complete: function(){
        bgColor = pageFill.fill;
        removeAnimation(fillAnimation);
      }
    });
    
    var ripple = new Circle({
      x: e.pageX,
      y: e.pageY,
      r: 0,
      fill: currentColor,
      stroke: {
        width: 3,
        color: currentColor
      },
      opacity: 1
    });
    var rippleAnimation = anime({
      targets: ripple,
      r: rippleSize,
      opacity: 0,
      easing: "easeOutExpo",
      duration: 900,
      complete: removeAnimation
    });
    
    var particles = [];
    for (var i=0; i<32; i++) {
      var particle = new Circle({
        x: e.pageX,
        y: e.pageY,
        fill: currentColor,
        r: anime.random(24, 48)
      })
      particles.push(particle);
    }
    var particlesAnimation = anime({
      targets: particles,
      x: function(particle){
        return particle.x + anime.random(rippleSize, -rippleSize);
      },
      y: function(particle){
        return particle.y + anime.random(rippleSize * 1.15, -rippleSize * 1.15);
      },
      r: 0,
      easing: "easeOutExpo",
      duration: anime.random(1000,1300),
      complete: removeAnimation
    });
    animations.push(fillAnimation, rippleAnimation, particlesAnimation);
}

function extend(a, b){
  for(var key in b) {
    if(b.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      a[key] = b[key];
    }
  }
  return a;
}

var Circle = function(opts) {
  extend(this, opts);
}

Circle.prototype.draw = function() {
  ctx.globalAlpha = this.opacity || 1;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  if (this.stroke) {
    ctx.strokeStyle = this.stroke.color;
    ctx.lineWidth = this.stroke.width;
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  if (this.fill) {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.fill;
    ctx.fill();
  }
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
}

var animate = anime({
  duration: Infinity,
  update: function() {
    ctx.fillStyle = bgColor;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, cW, cH);
    animations.forEach(function(anim) {
      anim.animatables.forEach(function(animatable) {
        animatable.target.draw();
      });
    });
  }
});

var resizeCanvas = function() {
  cW = window.innerWidth;
  cH = window.innerHeight;
  c.width = cW * devicePixelRatio;
  c.height = cH * devicePixelRatio;
  ctx.scale(devicePixelRatio, devicePixelRatio);
};

(function init() {
  resizeCanvas();
  if (window.CP) {
    // CodePen's loop detection was causin' problems
    // and I have no idea why, so...
    window.CP.PenTimer.MAX_TIME_IN_LOOP_WO_EXIT = 6000; 
  }
  window.addEventListener("resize", resizeCanvas);
  addClickListeners();
  if (!!window.location.pathname.match(/fullcpgrid/)) {
    startFauxClicking();
  }
  handleInactiveUser();
})();

function handleInactiveUser() {
  var inactive = setTimeout(function(){
    fauxClick(cW/2, cH/2);
  }, 2000);
  
  function clearInactiveTimeout() {
    clearTimeout(inactive);
    document.removeEventListener("mousedown", clearInactiveTimeout);
    document.removeEventListener("touchstart", clearInactiveTimeout);
  }
  
  document.addEventListener("mousedown", clearInactiveTimeout);
  document.addEventListener("touchstart", clearInactiveTimeout);
}

function startFauxClicking() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    fauxClick(anime.random( cW * .2, cW * .8), anime.random(cH * .2, cH * .8));
    startFauxClicking();
  }, anime.random(200, 900));
}

function fauxClick(x, y) {
  var fauxClick = new Event("mousedown");
  fauxClick.pageX = x;
  fauxClick.pageY = y;
  document.dispatchEvent(fauxClick);
}


implementing that effect into my project properly

Please add code, that you tried, so we can look into something, not just project structure. Also, you probably want to place it into +page.svelte / some component

Have you done the tutorials?

Right, so in svelte you'll create a file called Canvas.svelte (starting with the uppercase C) and put it into the src/routes directory. That file will look like this:
<script>

//this is where you put all the JS of the component

var c = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var cH;
var cW;
var bgColor = "#FF6138";
var animations = [];
var circles = [];

var colorPicker = (function() {
  var colors = ["#FF6138", "#FFBE53", "#2980B9", "#282741"];
  var index = 0;
  function next() {
    index = index++ < colors.length-1 ? index : 0;
    return colors[index];
  }
  function current() {
    return colors[index]
  }
  return {
    next: next,
    current: current
  }
})();

function removeAnimation(animation) {
  var index = animations.indexOf(animation);
  if (index > -1) animations.splice(index, 1);
}

function calcPageFillRadius(x, y) {
  var l = Math.max(x - 0, cW - x);
  var h = Math.max(y - 0, cH - y);
  return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(l, 2) + Math.pow(h, 2));
}

function addClickListeners() {
  document.addEventListener("touchstart", handleEvent);
  document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleEvent);
};

function handleEvent(e) {
    if (e.touches) { 
      e.preventDefault();
      e = e.touches[0];
    }
    var currentColor = colorPicker.current();
    var nextColor = colorPicker.next();
    var targetR = calcPageFillRadius(e.pageX, e.pageY);
    var rippleSize = Math.min(200, (cW * .4));
    var minCoverDuration = 750;
    
    var pageFill = new Circle({
      x: e.pageX,
      y: e.pageY,
      r: 0,
      fill: nextColor
    });
    var fillAnimation = anime({
      targets: pageFill,
      r: targetR,
      duration:  Math.max(targetR / 2 , minCoverDuration ),
      easing: "easeOutQuart",
      complete: function(){
        bgColor = pageFill.fill;
        removeAnimation(fillAnimation);
      }
    });
    
    var ripple = new Circle({
      x: e.pageX,
      y: e.pageY,
      r: 0,
      fill: currentColor,
      stroke: {
        width: 3,
        color: currentColor
      },
      opacity: 1
    });
    var rippleAnimation = anime({
      targets: ripple,
      r: rippleSize,
      opacity: 0,
      easing: "easeOutExpo",
      duration: 900,
      complete: removeAnimation
    });
    
    var particles = [];
    for (var i=0; i<32; i++) {
      var particle = new Circle({
        x: e.pageX,
        y: e.pageY,
        fill: currentColor,
        r: anime.random(24, 48)
      })
      particles.push(particle);
    }
    var particlesAnimation = anime({
      targets: particles,
      x: function(particle){
        return particle.x + anime.random(rippleSize, -rippleSize);
      },
      y: function(particle){
        return particle.y + anime.random(rippleSize * 1.15, -rippleSize * 1.15);
      },
      r: 0,
      easing: "easeOutExpo",
      duration: anime.random(1000,1300),
      complete: removeAnimation
    });
    animations.push(fillAnimation, rippleAnimation, particlesAnimation);
}

function extend(a, b){
  for(var key in b) {
    if(b.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      a[key] = b[key];
    }
  }
  return a;
}

var Circle = function(opts) {
  extend(this, opts);
}

Circle.prototype.draw = function() {
  ctx.globalAlpha = this.opacity || 1;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  if (this.stroke) {
    ctx.strokeStyle = this.stroke.color;
    ctx.lineWidth = this.stroke.width;
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  if (this.fill) {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.fill;
    ctx.fill();
  }
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
}

var animate = anime({
  duration: Infinity,
  update: function() {
    ctx.fillStyle = bgColor;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, cW, cH);
    animations.forEach(function(anim) {
      anim.animatables.forEach(function(animatable) {
        animatable.target.draw();
      });
    });
  }
});

var resizeCanvas = function() {
  cW = window.innerWidth;
  cH = window.innerHeight;
  c.width = cW * devicePixelRatio;
  c.height = cH * devicePixelRatio;
  ctx.scale(devicePixelRatio, devicePixelRatio);
};

(function init() {
  resizeCanvas();
  if (window.CP) {
    // CodePen's loop detection was causin' problems
    // and I have no idea why, so...
    window.CP.PenTimer.MAX_TIME_IN_LOOP_WO_EXIT = 6000; 
  }
  window.addEventListener("resize", resizeCanvas);
  addClickListeners();
  if (!!window.location.pathname.match(/fullcpgrid/)) {
    startFauxClicking();
  }
  handleInactiveUser();
})();

function handleInactiveUser() {
  var inactive = setTimeout(function(){
    fauxClick(cW/2, cH/2);
  }, 2000);
  
  function clearInactiveTimeout() {
    clearTimeout(inactive);
    document.removeEventListener("mousedown", clearInactiveTimeout);
    document.removeEventListener("touchstart", clearInactiveTimeout);
  }
  
  document.addEventListener("mousedown", clearInactiveTimeout);
  document.addEventListener("touchstart", clearInactiveTimeout);
}

function startFauxClicking() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    fauxClick(anime.random( cW * .2, cW * .8), anime.random(cH * .2, cH * .8));
    startFauxClicking();
  }, anime.random(200, 900));
}

function fauxClick(x, y) {
  var fauxClick = new Event("mousedown");
  fauxClick.pageX = x;
  fauxClick.pageY = y;
  document.dispatchEvent(fauxClick);
}
</script>

<!-- everything that's not in the <script> or <style> tags will be rendered as HTML -->
<canvas id="c"> </canvas>

<style>
    /* this is where you'll put all your CSS for this component */
    canvas {
        display: block;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
    }
</style>

Then in +page.svelte you can import it and render it like this:
<script>
    import Canvas from './'
</script>

<Canvas />

Check out the tutorial to learn more about reactivity in Svelte, good luck!
